# Vim have incorrect cursor

Tags: shell, vim, autocomplete

```
:ab psvm public static void main(String[] args){<CR><Space><Space><Space><Space><CR>}
```

I want to define a abb for java ,but it finished ,the cursor at the end. When I input psvm , I hope the cursor staying at `{}` ,instead of `{}behind`.

Comment: Hi can you be specific what exactly you want to perform? And your question seems unclear. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Mappings / abbreviations repeat the right-hand side as if it were typed. So, everything works as expected here. If you want to move the cursor, you can just append those moves, using the same `:help key-notation` you used for `<CR>` and `<Space>`, for example:

```
:ab psvm public static void main(String[] args){<CR><Space><Space><Space><Space><CR>}<Up><End>
```

---

However, that approach doesn't scale very well. You may want to upgrade to *snippets*, via a plugin:

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.